# vuex duplicate namespace auth/ for the namespaced module auth

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js, mixins, getter, vuex-modules

I am using nuxt.js with the auth module. 
Every time i open a new page on my profile this error message appears.
I have created a mixin called auth.js in my plugins/mixins directory. This file contains the code:

```
export const getters = {
    authenticated(state) {
        return state.loggedIn;
    },

    user(state){
        return state.user;
    }
};
```

I've created a getter file called auth.js with the following code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

const User = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.mixin({
            computed: {
                ...mapGetters({
                    user: 'auth/user',
                    authenticated: 'auth/authenticated'
                })
            }
        })
    }
};

Vue.use(User);
```

The getters and mixin work, but everytime i open a page it gives me this error and i dont know how to solve it. I've tried the solutions in this question:
[duplicate namespace auth/ for the namespaced module auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338642/duplicate-namespace-auth-for-the-namespaced-module-auth)
Altough this does solve the errors, it makes my getters undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I found a workable way ...
Switch to index.js auth.js logic, and delete auth.js.

index.js

```
export const getters = {
authenticated(state) {
  return state.auth.loggedIn
},

user(state) {
  return state.auth.user
}
}
```

Revise it as follows if you are using a user.js mixin:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'

const User = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.mixin({
            computed: {
                ...mapGetters({
                    user: 'user',
                    authenticated: 'authenticated'
                })
            }
        })
    }
};

Vue.use(User);
```

Plugins:

```
** Plugins to load before mounting the App
*/
plugins: ["./plugins/mixins/user.js"
],
```